# Design patterns when working with JSON web service and Core Data?

Tags: iphone, web-services, json, design-patterns

I have a iPhone app which loads json from my webservice.
I think its a good idea to store the data with Core Data but how should I sync the data with my webservice?

For example, say that I show a UITableView with the information stored in Core Data, and then I would like to update the object.

Are there any design patterns or ideas for this?

Comment: I've tried my best to edit and answer this question, but I'm not sure exactly what you are asking. Please add another sentence after "For Example..."

Answer (score 0):

Each time your app loads it should try to load info from the web service. If it can't connect, use the local data. You should timestamp your data on the server and in the app so that you can track when the information was last updated. You can also offer a button to manually refresh the data. (Like the Mail app.)

**EDIT:**

To make asynchronous requests, you can see the [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) library.

Comment: Thank you. Should i use FetechRequest Controller? Is it possible to load the json in a second thread and convert this data to my core data objects?

Comment: I'm not a Core Data expert, do I don't know aobut the FetchRequest Controller. You can load the JSON on the second thread.